# Arranging views in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have MFC MDI application. In my application I have 5 views. On a particular menu command ,  I have to show only 2 particular views(each have separate child window) and I have to arrange them in tile style.

If I call MDITile() function, it showing all 5 views in tile style.I need to display only 2 views vertically.

How to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the corresponding frame windows for the views with
   CView::GetParentFrame.
2. Now use ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE) for the windows you don't want to
   show.
3. From the CMainFrame query the Client Area.
4. rect1 = rectClient; rect1.bottom /= 2; MoveWindow...
5. rect2 = rectClient; rect1.top = rect.bottom/2; MoveWindow...